# python csv.dictreader not readin

Tags: python, csv, keyerror

I'm trying to read a csv file I've previously created with DictWriter, and it seems ok:

```
Long,Lat,Value
-4.46811978,36.71191819,21.836857418129924
-4.46829768,36.71214269,1.437288805738615
-4.46858762,36.71216232,1.4251383119025087
-4.46893456,36.71041284,1.4248025480555202
-4.46896851,36.71016468,0.00885256853534053
```

The problem is that I'm getting {'/': 'h'} when I try to read, so I get a KeyError: 'Value', because there is no Value key in that dictionary:

```
with open(path,'r') as file:
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(path)
    for line in csv_file:
        print line
        values.append(line["Value"])
        lat_long.append(line["Lat"],line["Long"])
    file.close()
```

I've printed the path to verify it is the right one, and it is, so I'm lost on how to solve this.

Comment: Please remove `file.close()`: a file opened with `with` is closed automatically. And why do you open the file at all, if you use the path name to create a reader?

Comment: does it? I didn't know it closes it automatically. I'll correct it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `csv.DictReader()` with `file` and not `path`.

If you pass `path` to `csv.DictReader()`, `csv.DictReader()` will parse the string `path` itself and not the file located at `path`.

Here is a correct version of your code:

```
with open(path,'r') as file:
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(file)
    for line in csv_file:
        print line
        values.append(line["Value"])
        lat_long.append(line["Lat"],line["Long"])
```

Comment: Super facepalm! Yesterday I spent 10 hours coding and I didn't see that big mistake despite looking and looking for almost an hour. I should have breaks more often